# 3 comboboxes have same items (aa, bb, cc, and dd). If I select “aa” in one of the comboxes, how to make it not appear again in the other 2 comboxes?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have 3 comboboxes namely combobox1, combobox2, and combobox3 with the same items each.
The items are, “aa”, “bb”, “cc”, and “dd”.

ALSO, these comboboxes are in the userform.

So, i have 3 comboboxes in USERFORM, 
if I select “aa” in combobox1, how can I make “aa” not appear in the other 2 comboboxes, so that it 
won’t be reselected again.

It’s like, if I select “aa” in combobox1, and “bb” in combobox2, the remaining items that is available in 
combobox3 must be “cc” and “dd”.

But I don’t know how to do it. Can you help me with the codes? Thank you a lot.

Ps. I am using Microsoft VBA in excel

Pps. I am not pro.

Comment: This looks very familiar... What have you tired already? Keep in mind this is not a code writing service but a question/answer site for code related problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic sample of how you can achieve what you are looking for. *You will need to change the code to work in your own project*.

This is assuming the user will make a selection from the ComboBoxes in a specific order every time. E.g. this will work for selecting a value from `ComboBox1` first and then provides the list for `ComboBox2` but won't work *(in its current form)* for removing `ComboBox2`'s selection from `ComboBox1` list. It can be modified to do so, so feel free to do that if need be.

You can write your list to a worksheet *anywhere* you want - generally it's useful to do so in a hidden column or hidden helper sheet. This example has the values "AA" to "GG" in cells `P6` to `P12` on `Sheet2` of the workbook.

The code loops through the range of your to to add items to the `ComboBox` 1 by 1, if the value is = the previous `ComboBox` selection then skip it otherwise add the value to the `ComboBox`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
'This Sub populates the first combobox with all values in the list

Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim ListRange As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ListRange = .Range("P6:P12")

    For Each TargetCell In ListRange
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem TargetCell.Value
    Next TargetCell
End With

End Sub
'__________________________________________________________________________________

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
'This Sub is similar to above, but has an If statement to check if the value on the sheet_
  'is the same as the selected value in the previous combobox1. If it is it's ignored_ 
    'otherwise Combobox2 has the value added.

Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim ListRange As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ListRange = .Range("P6:P12")

    For Each TargetCell In ListRange
        If TargetCell.Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
            'Skip
        Else
            Me.ComboBox2.AddItem TargetCell.Value
        End If
    Next TargetCell
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: UwU. Thank you!! 